# PHP: submit form and simultaneously save data

Tags: php, forms, redirect, curl, csv

i have a form with userdata, such as name, address, email etc. and i wanna do a action to a page on a foreign domain which i can not manipulate. Normally i would say that the form should do `action="www.notmydomain.com/externalscript.php"` to send the data via POST, but now i first wanna save this data an then submit the formdata to this target. This isn´t possible in this case so I tried to send my formdata to another script on MY server which saves the data an then reuses the POSTvars and send it with curl. This works so far but i need to redirect to www.notmydomain.com/theforeignscript.php so that the user ends at this domain. curl doesn´t do that because it only can do request, right?!

The first page shows the form:

```
<form id="newsletter" action="myscript.php" method="post">....</form>
```

..which is used by myscript.php to save the data in a csv and then again should submit the data to www.notmydomain.com/externalscript.php (which cannot be edited)...

Has anybody a hint how this could be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can send through `ajax` before submitting your form (submit when the ajax is complete). You can even print a form with your php code with hidden fields and add `onload="theform.submit()"` on the `body` tag, then you can save the data, print the form wich auto submits to the external page via post.

Comment: .....yes, this can be done with javascript...i thought there is a non-javascript way to get this working...but thank you, i will try it this way! already thought of that solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `header("Location: http://domain.com/script.php");` to redirect the user to another address. This needs to be executed before anything is printed by your script, so make sure you catch all curl errors etc. properly to avoid ugly PHP error messages.

Comment: Yes, i tried this but then the POST vars are empty an there is nothing transmitted to the external script...

Comment: You need to do this in addition to the POST request done via curl.

Comment: I changed the location before curl_exec() but then there where no post vars...after curl_exec(), there was no redirect...

Comment: You need to do the curl request first to submit the data to the target page. Afterwards you can do the redirect. You also could use the result of your curl request to show the user the result of the page you sent the data to.